# Quick Volume with Vertical Lines Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt with the graph:

"Let $M$ be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the graphs of $y=\arctan(x)$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{4}x$, as shown in the figure below. What is the volume of the solid generated when region $M$ is revolved around the vertical line $x=2$?"
[image]

So I guess I'm just a bit confused about what my volume equation might look like here. I understand that the equations here would both have to be expressed in terms of $y$, but I'm a bit lost about where to go after that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find volume of the area bound between curves $C1$ and $C2$ when rotated around $x = 2$

$C1: y=\frac{\pi}{4} x$ and $C2: y=\arctan x$ $(0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$)

When you rotate it around $x = 2$, please note the radius of the rotation of both curves at any given $y$.

For $C1$, $r = 2 - \frac{4y}{\pi}$

For $C2$, $r = 2 - \tan y$

So your triple integral to find volume should be $\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_{2 - \frac{4y}{\pi}}^{2 - \tan y} r \ dr \ dy \ d\theta$

Comment: So what were you getting for a volume here? I'm coming up with around $0.06$ and some clarification as to whether or not this is close to the correct answer would be appreciated.

Comment: No the answer is $ \approx 0.43$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The volume of the solid generated when region $M$ is revolved around the vertical line $x=2$ is the same of the volume you get rotating $M'$ around the orizontal line $y=2$ where $M'$ is defined as:
$$M' := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0\le x \le \frac{\pi}{4}, \ \tan x \le y \le \frac{4}{\pi} x\}$$

Or better, it is the same of the volume you get rotating $M''$ around the orizontal line $y=0$ where $M''$ is defined as:
$$M'' := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0\le x \le \frac{\pi}{4}, \ 2- \frac{4}{\pi} x  \le y \le 2-\tan x \} $$

The Volume you are searching for is then

$$ V = \pi \int_0^{\pi/4} {\left( {{{\left[ 2-\tan x \right]}^2} – {{\left[ 2- \frac{4}{\pi} x \right]}^2}} \right)dx} = \pi +\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2\pi\log 2 \sim 0.43$$

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused about what the actual equation would look like here? Are you saying that it might be something like $\int (tan(x)+2)-(\frac {4}{\pi}x+2)$ with bounds $(0,1)$?

Comment: No, now you have to use the easier formula for volumes obtained around the orizontal axis.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I'll correct theese errors

Comment: So what were you getting for a volume here? I'm coming up with around $0.06$ and some clarification as to whether or not this is close to the correct answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to @mathlover I edited the answer and the results is this.